# Zoom out automatically on iPhone safari browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, zooming, out

I have designed my webpage to fit an Iphone screen perfectly. It has a small text box in the top corner.
When the user clicks on the text box to type in the text, the Iphone browser automatically zooms into the top corner of the screen, which is totally cool. But after the user hits search the browser is still zoomed into the top corner. The user has to manually zoom out to see the full screen.

Hence I would like to know a way to fix this issue by calling a javascript that will zoom out automatically and shows the full web page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem/requirement, so I was hoping to find an answer here (which I haven't).

Here is what I've got so far:

Add an 'onblur' event handler to the text box mark-up (in the HTML, where you declare the text box).

The callback is triggered after the 'Done' button is pressed.

At this point, I'm not sure how to zoom out back to the previous zoom-level.